# Does curl's timeout include connect_timeout spent?

Tags: php, linux, curl, timeout

According to curl's docs `connect_timeout` is only for the time needed to connect to the server, however its not clear if `timeout` includes the `connect_timeout` period.

If I only set a `timeout` and the connection to the server takes a long time, will the timeout be reached even if there is no `connect_timeout` set?

Or if I have both set as below:

`connect_timeout => 10`

`timeout => 1`

If the connection takes more than 1 second will the timeout be reached?

- timeout https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.html
- connect_timeout https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I could easily test this myself using curl.

```bash
$ curl --max-time 1  --connect-timeout 0.01 https://stackoverflow.com
```

> curl: (28) **Resolving** timed out after 10 milliseconds

```bash
$ curl --max-time 0.01  --connect-timeout 1 https://stackoverflow.com
```

> curl: (28) **Connection** timed out after 10 milliseconds

So in conclusion `timeout` which is equivalent to `max-time` includes the whole time spent including the connecting time, so you can safely only set a `timeout` and it should also deal with connecting timing issues.